Closing a httpx client results in a "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed"
I need to maintain a persistent httpx client in my code to utilize its connection pool throughout the lifespan of my application. Below is a simplified version of my implementation:
import asyncio
import weakref
from threading import Lock

import nest_asyncio
from httpx import AsyncClient


class Request:
    _instance = None
    _lock = Lock()
    _loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop = None
    _new_loop = False
    _session = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if not cls._instance:
            with cls._lock:
                if not cls._instance:
                    instance = super().__new__(cls)
                    cls._instance = instance
                    weakref.finalize(instance, instance._close)

                    if cls._loop is None:
                        try:
                            cls._loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
                        except RuntimeError:
                            cls._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                            cls._new_loop = True
                            asyncio.set_event_loop(cls._loop)

                if cls._new_loop:
                    # nest_asyncio.apply()
                    cls._loop.run_until_complete(cls.create_client())
                else:
                    cls._loop.create_task(cls.create_client())

        return cls._instance

    @classmethod
    async def create_client(cls):
        cls._session = AsyncClient()

    @classmethod
    def _close(cls):
        cls._loop.run_until_complete(cls.close())

        if cls._new_loop:
            cls._loop.close()

    @classmethod
    async def close(cls):
        if cls._session:
            await cls._session.aclose()

    async def get(self, url):
        try:
            return await self._session.get(url)

        except Exception:
            return None


req = Request()


async def main():
    result = await req.get('https://www.google.com')
    if result:
        print(result.text[:100])


asyncio.run(main())

This results in a RuntimeError: Event loop is closed:
...
    await self._pool.aclose()
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-gEFTwlce-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 313, in aclose
    await self._close_connections(closing_connections)
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-gEFTwlce-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 305, in _close_connections
    await connection.aclose()
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-gEFTwlce-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 171, in aclose
    await self._connection.aclose()
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-gEFTwlce-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http11.py", line 265, in aclose
    await self._network_stream.aclose()
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-gEFTwlce-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/anyio.py", line 55, in aclose
    await self._stream.aclose()
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-gEFTwlce-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 201, in aclose
    await self.transport_stream.aclose()
  File "/home/user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-gEFTwlce-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 1287, in aclose
    self._transport.close()
  File "/nix/store/gmx7bwrwy6s0kk89ij5yj8r8ayai95x1-python3-3.12.5/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1210, in close
    super().close()
  File "/nix/store/gmx7bwrwy6s0kk89ij5yj8r8ayai95x1-python3-3.12.5/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 875, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "/nix/store/gmx7bwrwy6s0kk89ij5yj8r8ayai95x1-python3-3.12.5/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 795, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/nix/store/gmx7bwrwy6s0kk89ij5yj8r8ayai95x1-python3-3.12.5/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

The only way to resolve this issue is to uncomment the line containing nest_asyncio.apply(). However, since the nest_asyncio package is heavily based on asyncio internal functions and is no longer maintained, I'm not interested in using it in my code.
My question is: Why is the loop closed when I call run_until_complete() (from within the _close() function), which creates a new event loop and immediately calls the AyncClient.aclose() function? How can I fix this?
For your reference, the same code works for aiohttp.ClientSession without the need to use nest_asyncio.

I am not sure if it is even necessary to call aclose on the session since in the code you have posted this would only occur at program termination when your global Request instance is garbage collected. But if you really wanted to, then it appears that if you wait until program termination it will be too late and so I believe the best you can do (or at least the best I can do) is:
import asyncio
import threading

from httpx import AsyncClient

class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._instance = None
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._instance is None:
            with self._lock:
                if self._instance is None:
                    self._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self._instance

class Request(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self._session = AsyncClient()

    async def close(self):
        await self._session.aclose()

    async def get(self, url):
        try:
            return await self._session.get(url)
        except Exception:
            return None

req = Request()

async def _main():
    result = await req.get('https://www.google.com')
    if result:
        print(result.text[:100])

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(_main())
    loop.run_until_complete(req.close())
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I have created a Singleton type that can simplify the creation of singleton instances. I have added synchronization using a lock in case multiple threads are trying to create the singleton concurrently from multiple threads for the general case. But that does not seem particularly relevant here.

In my real project, I created a singleton class similar, but more complex, than yours. I've simplified it here for clarity. Closing the client is necessary to avoid numerous ResourceWarning warnings if they are enabled. I utilize the singleton instance of the Request class across various places and potentially create additional instances in other modules (if they are used to request from different domains). Therefore, I’m uncertain where the application exit point would be to close the client. The class itself should handle closing it.
